# i am doing an add to cart program.i am listing several products on a single page.but i can only change the quantity of the first product

Tags: php

I am new to php. i am doing an add to cart program.i am listing several products on a single page.but i can only change the quantity of the first product in the list. while the others taking the default value 1.

this program is used for listing multiple products on a single page retrieving from the database.there are different categories and therefore i am taking the cat_id from the URL.

```
custproduct.php

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // echo"id: ".$_GET['id'];
include ('custdb1.php');
echo "<h2>List of Products:</h2>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `cat_id`=".$_GET['id'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br> Product ID: ". $row["pro_id"]. " - Product Name: ". $row["pro_name"]. "<br>";
echo "<img src='upload/".$row['pro_img']."'/>";
echo "<br> Price: Rs. ". $row["pro_price"]. " ";
echo "<br>";
 echo "Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='1'>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<button onclick='addtocart(".$row['pro_id'].")'>Add To Cart</button>" ;
}

}
}
else {
     echo "0 results";
}

?>

 <script>

function addtocart(id)
{

var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
document.write("qty");
window.location ="cart.php?id="+id+"&qty="+qty;

}

</script>
```

this is cart.php page.this page is used to add the products in the cart.the customer will see his cart by clicking the link below "see list"

```
 <?php

session_start();

include('custdb1.php');
//$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id=$_REQUEST["id"];
  $qty=$_REQUEST["qty"];
//echo"qty=".$qty;

$_SESSION['cart'][$id] =  array('id'=> $id,'qty'=> $qty);

$sql = "SELECT `pro_img` FROM `product` WHERE `pro_id`=".$id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "quantity:".$qty.'<br>';
 echo "id:".$id.'<br>';
echo "<img src='upload/".$row['pro_img']."'/>";

     }
}
}
echo "<h4 align='center'>  click here to <a href='shoppingcart.php'>see list</a> </h4>";
echo "<h4 align='center'>  click here to <a href='custprofile.php'>Continue Shopping</a> </h4>";
?>
```

this is shopping cart.php.this page shows the added products in the cart...i.e the customer can see his cart.

```
<?php

session_start();
include('custdb1.php');
echo "<pre>";

$value=$_SESSION['cart'];
//print_r($value);
foreach ( $value as $key=> $final_val ){

              $cat_id = $key;
              $pro_id = $final_val['id'];
              $qty = $final_val['qty'];
            echo"product id:".$pro_id;
            echo"quantity:".$qty;
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `pro_id`=".$pro_id;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Product ID: ". $row["pro_id"]. " - Product Name: ". $row["pro_name"]. "<br>";
        echo "<img src='upload/".$row['pro_img']."'/>";
       // echo "<button onclick='update(".$row['pro_id'].")'>update</button>" ;
      // echo "<h4 align='left'><a href='update.php'>update cart</a> </h4>";
}

}
else {
     echo "0 results";
}
}

echo "<h4 align='center'>  click here to <a href='custprofile.php'>Continue Shopping</a> </h4>";
?>
```

Comment: you cannot have multiple same ids in your quantity input type html.Firstly correct that error and then tell us if your program is working correctly or not

Comment: Check the solution I have given below and try it and tell me if it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Set the id of the quantity html with the product id

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br> Product ID: ". $row["pro_id"]. " - Product Name: ". $row["pro_name"]. "<br>";
echo "<img src='upload/".$row['pro_img']."'/>";
echo "<br> Price: Rs. ". $row["pro_price"]. " ";
echo "<br>";
 echo "Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty' id='". $row["pro_id"]. "' value='1'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<button onclick='addtocart(".$row['pro_id'].")'>Add To Cart</button>" ;
```

}

Then can select the input element with the corresponding product id set as its id

```
function addtocart(id)
{

var qty = document.getElementById(id).value;
document.write("qty");
window.location ="cart.php?id="+id+"&qty="+qty;

}
```